# Why is my voltage so low?

Tags: electrical

I have very low voltage at times hovering around 99v, usually when the A/C is on and everyone in my area is running theirs as well. I have 240v outlets for my appliances and wanted to know if there is a way to step down the 240v circuit to provide a constant 120v to my home.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to start by contacting your service provider, and asking them if there is a problem with their distribution system. Ask if they're providing poor service due to high demand. If they're not aware of any problems in your area, you should ask them if they can come out and verify you have a good hookup.  If everything with the electric company checks out, you'll want to have a licensed Electrician come have a look inside your home.